# cannot use response data in pipe respronse undefined in log

Tags: logging, pipe, undefined, response, pentaho-data-integration

```
let dataIn:any;
const member = (await this.apiGatewayService.userInfo(event.source.userId))
.pipe(map((response) => {
    console.log("response", response);
    dataIn = response.data
}))
.pipe(
    catchError(error => {
    throw new HttpException(error.response.status, error.response.status);
    }),
);

    console.log("log",dataIn);
```

```
  async userInfo(lineId: string) {
    const API_GATEWAY_URL = process.env.API_GATEWAY_URL;
    const user = await this.authService.getToken();
    const headersRequest = {
      "authorization": `Bearer ${user.access_token}`,
    };
    return this.httpService
      .post(`${API_GATEWAY_URL}/users-line/userInfo`,
        {
          "lineId": lineId
        }, {
        headers: headersRequest,
      })
      .pipe(map((response) => {
        return response.data
      }))
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          throw new HttpException(error.response.status, error.response.status);
        }),
      );
  }
```

cannot use response data in pipe

It is not possible to retrieve data in an API call outside of a function.

respronse undefined in log
but not error